# Powershell & Plink - formatting commands

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to push some commands to plink from within a powershell script.

I have it working, except if there is a space in the file name.

```
$entry.name = "File with a space.txt"

$SSH_Source = "/share/USBDisk1"

$Files = $SSH_Source+$entry.Name
```

When I push `$Files` to plink it truncates after the space in the file name.

I need it to output like this with the single quotes so that plink works correctly.

```
/share/USBDisk1/'File with a space.txt'
```

Thank in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$entry.name = "'File with a space.txt'"
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am pulling the file names from a CSV column named Name. I've tried wrapping it in single quotes every which way and none work.

Comment: Post the part of code where you assign the value of `$entry.name`. If is from a pipe you can do: `$entry.name = "'$_'"`

Comment: Here is where I get the entry value: foreach ($entry in $CSV){

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to be doing something like:

```
$entryname = "File with a space.txt"
$SSH_Source = "/share/USBDisk1"
$Files = '"' + $SSH_Source + '/' + $entryname + '"'
$Files
```

You want the quotes around the full path, something like:

```
"/share/USBDisk1/File with a space.txt"
```